# Convert char array to single int?

Tags: c++, char, int

Anyone know how to convert a char array to a single int?

```
char hello[5];
hello = "12345";

int myNumber = convert_char_to_int(hello);
Printf("My number is: %d", myNumber);
```

Comment: Does that code compile as is? It shouldn't.

Comment: It's not supposed to. convert_char_to_int(hello) is not an actual function. I'm asking what function/method I should use to replace my theoretical: "convert_char_to_int(hello)" ?

Comment: `hello` is a non modifiable *lvalue* so `hello = "12345";` won't even compile.

Comment: All right then, this one: http://codepad.org/oSgK5nK4 How do I convert it?

Comment: Are you absolutely stuck with C-style constructs like char arrays and printf? If not, have a look at `std::string` for the characters, C++ iostreams for printing the output (`std::cout`), and `boost::lexical_cast` for the conversion (as has already been pointed out).

Comment: you assign 6 characters to an array with a size of 5. Remember your null terminator. You'd better use strings. And if you can't then at least initialize at declaration time to avoid issues like that. `char hello[] = "12345";`

Answer (score 46):

There are mulitple ways of converting a string to an int.

***Solution 1:  Using Legacy C functionality***

```
int main()
{
    //char hello[5];     
    //hello = "12345";   --->This wont compile

    char hello[] = "12345";

    Printf("My number is: %d", atoi(hello)); 

    return 0;
}
```

***Solution 2: Using `lexical_cast`(Most Appropriate & simplest)***

```
int x = boost::lexical_cast<int>("12345");
```

***Solution 3: Using `C++ Streams`***

```
std::string hello("123"); 
std::stringstream str(hello); 
int x;  
str >> x;  
if (!str) 
{      
   // The conversion failed.      
}
```

Comment: @Als: Use `boost::lexical_cast`. `atoi` is not safe!

Comment: @Nawaz: I guess that sums it all up :)

Comment: +1. By the way, you should put `boost::lexical_cast` in try-catch block. It throws `boost::bad_lexical_cast` when the cast is invalid.

Comment: ...instead of `atoi` `strtol` should be used and in this case is more apt - no need to use boost just for this simple operation...

Comment: @Nim But what is wrong with using boost, even for this simple example? What does using strtol gain you?

Comment: @juanchopanza An error code, rather than an exception.  If you're handling user input (and why else would you be converting), error codes are generally more appropriate than exceptions.

Comment: @juanchopanza, there were (and still are perfectly good) ways of doing things before boost came along - don't get me wrong, I'm a huge fan of boost (if you see my answers you'll realise this), however, sometimes there are are far simpler and more appropriate ways of doing things... :)

Comment: @Nim, sure, I was just curious as to why it might be more appropriate. @James Kanze has mentioned error codes vs. exceptions. Personally I use boost::lexical_cast everywhere and haven't come across a situation where it didn't seem appropriate.

Comment: Why is atoi not safe?

Comment: What about the stoi and stol functions in c++11? For example `std::stoi("1234")`

Answer (score 11):

If you are using `C++11`, you should probably use `stoi` because it can distinguish between an error and parsing `"0"`.

```
try {
    int number = std::stoi("1234abc");
} catch (std::exception const &e) {
    // This could not be parsed into a number so an exception is thrown.
    // atoi() would return 0, which is less helpful if it could be a valid value.
}
```

It should be noted that "1234abc" is [implicitly converted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/121162/what-does-the-explicit-keyword-in-c-mean) from a `char[]` to a `std:string` before being passed to `stoi()`.

Answer (score 3):

I use :

```
int convertToInt(char a[1000]){
    int i = 0;
    int num = 0;
    while (a[i] != 0)
    {
        num =  (a[i] - '0')  + (num * 10);
        i++;
    }
    return num;;
}
```

Comment: @Fateh aren't you mistaking '0' (character for digit zero, ASCII code 48) and actual 0 byte value, which signalizes end of a string?

Answer (score 1):

Use [sscanf](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdio/sscanf/)

```
/* sscanf example */
#include <stdio.h>

int main ()
{
  char sentence []="Rudolph is 12 years old";
  char str [20];
  int i;

  sscanf (sentence,"%s %*s %d",str,&i);
  printf ("%s -> %d\n",str,i);

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Not like that, at any rate.  Never use a `"%s"`, for example, since that will result in buffer overflow.  All in all, `stdtol` is a lot simpler and safer.

Comment: Isn't `strtol`? Why is `strtol` better than `atoi`?

Comment: @qed For atoi, "if the value of the result cannot be represented, the behavior is undefined".  With strtol, the behavior is defined for all input.

Answer (score 1):

I'll just leave this here for people interested in an implementation with no dependencies.

```
inline int
stringLength (char *String)
    {
    int Count = 0;
    while (*String ++) ++ Count;
    return Count;
    }

inline int
stringToInt (char *String)
    {
    int Integer = 0;
    int Length = stringLength(String);
    for (int Caret = Length - 1, Digit = 1; Caret >= 0; -- Caret, Digit *= 10)
        {
        if (String[Caret] == '-') return Integer * -1;
        Integer += (String[Caret] - '0') * Digit;
        }

    return Integer;
    }
```

Works with negative values, but can't handle non-numeric characters mixed in between (should be easy to add though). Integers only.

Answer (score 1):

For example, "mcc" is a char array and "mcc_int" is the integer you want to get.

```
char mcc[] = "1234";
int mcc_int;
sscanf(mcc, "%d", &mcc_int);
```

Answer (score 0):

With cstring and cmath:

```
int charsToInt (char* chars) {

    int res{ 0 };

    int len = strlen(chars);

    bool sig = *chars == '-';
    if (sig) {
        chars++;
        len--;
    }

    for (int i{ 0 }; i < len; i++) {
        int dig = *(chars + i) - '0';
        res += dig * (pow(10, len - i - 1));
    }

    res *= sig ? -1 : 1;

    return res;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Ascii string to integer conversion is done by the `atoi()` function.

Comment: That's one you should definitely avoid.  How do you check for errors?

Answer (score -2):

Long story short you have to use [atoi()](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdlib/atoi/)

ed:

If you are interested in doing this [the right way](http://www.iso-9899.info/wiki/Converting) :

```
char szNos[] = "12345";
char *pNext;
long output;
output = strtol (szNos, &pNext, 10); // input, ptr to next char in szNos (null here), base
```

Comment: No you don't and you should not in any new code - use `strtol` instead!

Comment: @Nim I'm aware of that, but for a newbie like OP, I guess its ok to let him/her use it, just for the sake of understanding this concept. I guess that is why others have suggested the same api too.

Comment: @harper There is no `itoa` in standard C++.  And the traditional interface for it is broken, and can result in buffer overflows.

Comment: @Reno In **no** case should a beginner be encouraged to develop bad habits.