# C++ Parse string to integer with specific classes

Tags: c++, string, parsing, integer

It might sound stupid, but I was just wondering how can I parse a string to an integer in C++?

This is for a school project, and the explanation sheet says :
**"Only the use of `iostream` and `string` classes and `system()` function is permitted; The use of any other class or function is prohibited."**

I have searched around a bit, but the only suggestions I found are using classes like `atoi` or `atof`.

The input string is already checked for error before the parsing, so it will always only contain an integer.

I wouldn't mind doing the parsing manually with conditionals, but I don't think it would be my teacher's (or anyone's) preferred way.

Thanks a bunch if you can help.

Comment: Are you allowed to use Boost?

Comment: I don't suppose you are allowed to use stringstream?

Comment: No, the explanation sheet clearly says "Only the use of iostream and string classes and system() function is permitted; The use of any other class or function is prohibited."

Comment: Well, `atoi` and `atof` are functions (not classes). And they are not .NET specific (ANSI C in fact). Ask your teacher about it, but I don't think it is really a big deal to use it

Comment: possible duplicate of [Convert char array to single int?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6093414/convert-char-array-to-single-int)

Comment: I wouldn't consider it as duplicate, since I am limited to using only the aforementioned classes and function.

Comment: `stringstream`s *are* iostream classes. See http://cplusplus.com/reference/iostream/stringstream/.

Comment: I wonder why `system()` is allowed.

Comment: Hmm. I wonder if the prof meant only `class iostream` and `class string`, or if he meant "only those classes defined in `<iostream>` and `<string>`.  There are more classes in `<iostream>` than just `iostream`.

Comment: `system()` is allowed to people using MS Windows IDEs that auto-launch a command prompt window to run your console-mode program can do `system("pause");`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int stringToInt(const std::string &text)
{
    int number = 0;

    int powerIndex = 1;

    for (int i = text.length() - 1; i >= 0; i--)
    {
        number += powerIndex * (text.at(i) - '0');

        powerIndex *= 10;
    }

    return number;
}

std::string intToString (int number)
{
    std::string text = "";

    int numberHolder = number;

    while (numberHolder)
    {
        char digit = (numberHolder % 10) + '0';

        text = digit + text;

        numberHolder /= 10;
    }

    return text;

}
int main ()
{
    //Testing...

    int number = stringToInt("123");

    std::string text = intToString(456);

    std::cout << number << "\n" << text << "\n";

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Usually, primitive types like `int` (and char, short, long, float, double, ...) are passed *by value*, not by reference.

Answer (score 40):

So, you can use `system()`, huh? Behold this masterpiece of engineering:

```
#include <fstream>

void download_boost() {
    system("wget http://downloads.sourceforge.net/"
           "project/boost/boost/1.47.0/boost_1_47_0.tar.bz2"
           "?r=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.boost.org%2Fusers%2Fhistory%2F"
           "version_1_47_0.html&ts=1316116936&use_mirror=kent"
           " -O boost_1_47_0.tar.bz2");
}

void unpack_boost() {
    system("tar --bzip2 -xf boost_1_47_0.tar.bz2");
}

void write_program() {
    std::ofstream os("blah.cpp");
    os << "#include \"boost/lexical_cast.hpp\"\n"
          "#include <iostream>\n"
          "#include <string>\n"
          "int main() { std::string s; std::cin >> s;"
          "int i = boost::lexical_cast<int>(s);"
          "std::cout << i; }";
}

void compile_program() {
    system("g++ -Iboost_1_47_0 blah.cpp");
}

void run_program() {
    system("./a.out");
}

int main() {
    download_boost();
    unpack_boost();
    write_program();
    compile_program();
    run_program();
}
```

(I'm assuming a typical Linux installation with some common tools installed.)

Comment: Now that's what I call lateral thinking!

Comment: Literal thinking. Thinking with literals.

Comment: Cute. But, you used `std::ofstream`, which is not allowed.

Comment: @Rob: I think the text is ambiguous enough to wonder if it allows the `iostream` class, the class in the `<iostream>` header or the classes in the iostream library. But well, it's a joke anyway.

Comment: If you don't want to use ofstream then you can just echo out your code, and pipe it into G++: `echo CODE | g++ -x cpp -` (Who needs to do any of this with C++?)

Comment: @VolatileStorm: That would probably require shell escaping for the echo part. I'll need to work on that later.

Comment: At the end of `write_program`, shouldn't `std::cout >> i;` be `std::cout << i;`?

Answer (score 2):

`stringstream`s come closest to what you want to do, although it may seem a little cumbersome at first.

Example:

```
#include <string>
#include <sstream>

// (...)
std::string str = "12345";
std::istringstream ss(str);
int num;
ss >> num;
```

As a **function** (and optimized):

```
#include <sstream>
#include <string>

int stringToInt(const std::string &str) {
    static std::istringstream ss;
    ss.clear();
    ss.str(str);

    int num;
    ss >> num;

    return num;
}
```

Here, I am **reusing** the `std::istringstream` by applying the `static` keyword. I have created a very simple benchmark that demonstrates that this is approximately 2 times faster than *not* reusing: http://pastebin.com/vLSmCyMF

**Warning regarding thread-safety:** As рытфолд has noted in the comments, the above implementation of `stringToInt` is not thread-safe. If you want to call this function safely from multiple threads, you should use the `thread_local` storage class specifier (available since C++11).

Comment: `std::ostringstream("1234")` would be enough

Comment: I just added some extra information in bold text to my question.

Comment: Thanks, Andy. I have adapted the code to demonstrate that `stringstream`s can be reused, while `ostringstream`s cannot. It would be interesting to determine if my way of doing it is *actually* faster. I'm not sure.

Comment: @AgentRev: Technically, stringstream is both an iostream _and_ a string class in the standard library.

Comment: @SoapBox: I have appended additional results with -O3 switch. It appears that it makes no difference in this specific case. (Or is there anything wrong with the compilation command?)

Comment: This isn't thread-safe. Use `thread_local` instead of `static`.

Comment: @рытфолд: Thanks for pointing out! I updated my answer with a warning about thread-safety.

Answer (score 1):

```
std::string mystring = "12";

std::ostringstream str(mystring);
int someint;
str >> someint;
```

Comment: `std::ostream`? probably you meant `std::ostringstream`

Comment: @Andy T: Yes, indeed! Fixed it

Comment: I'm pretty sure ostringstream doesn't have operator>> (only <<). I think it should be istringstream instead.

Comment: I just added some extra information in bold text to my question.

Comment: Remember to test str.fail() after using operator>>.

Answer (score 1):

Basically, given a `std::string mystring` that contains only an integer:
Start with an `int result = 0;`.
While mystring has digits
   Multiply result by ten
   Add biggest digit (first in string)
       Remember that the character '0' does not have the value of 0.
   Remove the biggest digit from the string

So:
If I have the string "1543", result = 0
we multiply result by ten : result = 0
we add the first digit: result = 1
remove the first digit from the string "543"
we multiply result by ten : result = 10
we add the first digit: result = 15
remove the first digit from the string "43"
we multiply result by ten : result = 150
we add the first digit: result = 154
remove the first digit from the string "3"
we multiply result by ten : result = 1540
we add the first digit: result = 1543
remove the first digit from the string ""
string is empty, so we're done

I wrote code, but then remembered this was a homework problem.

Comment: This is assuming stringstream is not allowed