# Converting a char array in C++ into int

Tags: c++

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Convert char array to single int?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6093414/convert-char-array-to-single-int)

I have

> char[] str = "124"

I want to get a single int `i` with `i==124`.
Which function do I have to use?

Comment: You need to specify more. What do you want for "1E20"? "1E3000000"? "124Hello"? "Hello"? ""? "2,3"? "2.3"? "00000124"?

Comment: In C++ you say `char str[] = "124"`.

Comment: ¤ Learning to find things in the documentation is one of the most important skills to develop for a beginner. So concentrate on that. Read the documentation, get familiar with it, try to find things before asking here. Or as we said in the old days, with less sensitive learners (or perhaps the point was to weed out the sensitive soft-minded ones), RTFM. Cheers & hth.,

Answer (score 6):

`std::istringstream`, or `boost::lexical_cast`, if you have Boost.

Answer (score 1):

Try [atoi()](http://linux.die.net/man/3/atoi) from the C standard library:

```
#include <cstdlib>

char str[] = "124";
int i = atoi(str);
```

Or, possibly better, use [strtol()](http://linux.die.net/man/3/strtol):

```
#include <cstdlib>

char str[] = "124";
int i = strtol(str, NULL, 0);
```

Comment: Don't use `atoi`.  There's no error handling.  (But `strtol` is a good alternative, which I failed to mention.)

Comment: @James: thanks - I've updated the answer with `strtol()` as a possibly better alternative to `atoi()`.

Answer (score 0):

Use atoi function.

Alse see;

[Atoi](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdlib/atoi/)

[Strtol](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdlib/strtol/)

[Strtod](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdlib/strtod/)

[Strtoul](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdlib/strtoul/)

Answer (score 0):

Create a stringstream from the char-Array and use << for conversion to int.