# How to convert char array to uintmax_t?

Tags: c++, c

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Convert char array to single int?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6093414/convert-char-array-to-single-int)

How to convert char array to uintmax_t?
char array contains the uintMax_t value but in string format.
Thank you.

Comment: C or C++?  [What have you tried?](http://whathaveyoutried.com)

Comment: How is this different from converting character string to integer, which might have dozens of duplicate already?

Comment: I was thinking that atoi function will convert only string to integer but not the long integer. I thought this function might not work. But I tried in following way and it is working:
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <stdint.h>
int main ()
{
  time_t rawtime;
  char s1[64];
  uintmax_t u1;
  rawtime = time(NULL);
  printf ( "Current local time : %ju \n",(uintmax_t)rawtime );
  sprintf(s1,"%ju",(uintmax_t)rawtime);
  printf ( "Current local time : %s \n",s1 );
  u1 = atoi(s1);
  printf ( "Current local time : %ju \n",u1 );
return 0;
} Have I tried right?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `atoi` or `atol` .

Comment: Yes thanks. I have used it in this way. Is it correct?
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <stdint.h>
int main ()
{
  time_t rawtime;
  char s1[64];
  uintmax_t u1;
  rawtime = time(NULL);
  printf ( "Current local time : %ju \n",(uintmax_t)rawtime );
  sprintf(s1,"%ju",(uintmax_t)rawtime);
  printf ( "Current local time : %s \n",s1 );
  u1 = atoi(s1);
  printf ( "Current local time : %ju \n",u1 );
return 0;
}

Comment: Compile and run it. Does it work?