# C++ Command Line Arguments

Tags: c++, command-line-arguments

I'm learning C++ for school and I'm confused on how to integrate command line arguments into my code

```
    int n = 1;
    int c = 0;
    n = argv[1];
    c = int(argv[2]);
    findPrimes(n, c); 
    return 0;
}
```

That's my main function so far, but n = argv[1]; is a type error, and c = int(argv[2]); is a loss of data error. I know I'm rather far off, so any help to both improve my question and solve my problem is appreciated.

Comment: argv is an array of c-strings.  You need to convert the string into the correct thing.

Comment: Ok, my C++ array knowledge is bad at best, how would I go about doing that? @NathanOliver

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6093414/convert-char-array-to-single-int

Comment: OT: You should always verify that the correct number of arguments was passed. Your program would exhibit UB if the user failed to type the required arguments.

Comment: I start my C++ code this way:  `int main(int argc, char** argv) { vector<string> args(argv+1, argv+argc); /*...*/` which I find easier to work with a vector of strings rather than C style argc and argv.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To convert a `char*` string into an `int`, you can use the C library `atoi()`, `sscanf()` or other equivalent function:

```
#include <cstdlib>

int n = std::atoi(argv[1]);
```

```
#include <cstdio>

int n;
std::sprintf(argv[1], "%d", &n);
```

Or, you can use the C++ `std:stoi()` function:

```
#include <string>

int n = std::stoi(argv[1]);
```

Or, the C++ `std::istringstream` stream class:

```
#include <sstream>

int n;
std::istringstream(argv[1]) >> n;
```

Comment: Your first suggestion was great, it worked perfectly, thanks for the help.